# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine Please give me a solution

Tags: django, django-templates

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 63281)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\ramkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "c:\users\ramkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "c:\users\ramkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in **init**
self.handle()
File "D:\customerApplication\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
File "D:\customerApplication\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
File "c:\users\ramkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `D:\customerApplication\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py`, find the `is_broken_pipe_error()` function and change the return value from `return issubclass(exc_type, BrokenPipeError)` to `return issubclass(exc_type, BrokenPipeError) or issubclass(exc_type, ConnectionAbortedError)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase client-side timout and disabling firewall/anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I sorted it out by adding at the beginning of the view

```
time.sleep(.10)
```

I think it is connected with the view loading your data set before they are recorded in your DB.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    time.sleep(.10)
    context = self.get_context_data()
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```